# Making an Inductor with Proper Inductance

Tags: inductor, high-voltage, inductance

## Background

I am planning to build a 0.0625 mH inductor, which will be sent about 15 kV max (10 uS pulses, 10 per second).

The inductor will be made of 14 AWG copper wire in a tub of mineral oil. The copper will have 34 turns, each loop having a diameter of in inches.

## Question

Is it accurate to say that standard mineral oil (such as [this Walmart food grade mineral oil](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Food-Grade-Mineral-Oil-1-Gallon-128oz-for-Cutting-Boards-and-Butcher-Blocks-Stainless-Steel-and-More-NSF-Approved/546685251))
will have a relative permeability around 2? Typically, mineral oil is rated to have a permeability between 2.1 and 2.4, however this sample is from Walmart after all.

As a side question, would this work well to provide insulation?

Comment: food-grade mineral oil – the US never ceases to amaze me. Honestly, I'd assume that every motor oil would be better in terms of reliable isolation, because if one thing, than kitchen-grade stuff doesn't care about the moisture content of that oil.

Comment: Do you mean relative **permittivity**? I would not expect much in the way of magnetic effects from mineral oil unless it's spent a lot of time in a well-worn crankcase.

Comment: The purpose of putting a coil into oil is to suppress corona discharge and improve heat dissipation.  Free space has a permittivity of 1, so a permittivity of 2 will support a higher voltage without arcing. The oil is pretty inert when it comes to interacting with magnetic  fields.

Comment: Why not use transformer oil? It's available in small quantities on the internet for reasonable prices.

Comment: @DDuck Thank you, any recommendations for good places to get transformer oil? The standard players (eBay, Amazon, HVStuf) don't seem to be much good.

Comment: This is NOT how to define a good question or a good design with full specifications . Oil is a good HV insulator , if the PPM contamination level is LOW for: { moisture, contaminants, oxidants, acid content and dissolved combustible gas } . Specify all all input / output current, power duration or spectrum and purpose of the 10 Hz arc. Why can't you use a spark plug and ignition circuit? and also define arc peak current & energy of discharge

Comment: @Marcus Müller: Food grade mineral oil is a thing. You need it for cosmetics. Petrolatum, Vaseline, it's the same thing. The advantage is you don't need preservatives or antioxidants then.

Comment: @Joshua Guertler: Don't use oil unless you need to get rid of a lot of heat. It's an additional complication. If you just need better HV properties, use PTFE-hosed wires.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Well, we put propylene glycol into apple juice here so that it does not sediment on the bottom while it sits on a store shelf for a long time! Double blind tests say that consumers like it better, too. We also just a few years ago worked out how to modify corn pollen so that it modifies other crops related to kale and broccoli (for example) to convert them from diploid to haploid so they produce better.$$$$"The key innovation is using haploid inducer pollen as a sort of Trojan Horse,” says Kelliher, whose Syngenta-led team describes the system today in Nature Biotechnology.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Just keep buying American over there in Germany, I say. (By the way, in the US it is legal to place propylene glycol under the "contents" entry name of "natural flavors." I kid you not.)

Comment: Propylene Glycol (PG) an alcohal is  confused with toxic Ethylene Glycol (EG), as both have been used in antifreeze due to their low melting points. However, these are not the same substance.  Vegetable based transformer oils are preferred now due to higher water absorption tolerance before PD effects. But where are the real design specs of this question in doubt?.  Beware of lower explosive level of 4% for H2 content. for mineral oil.

Comment: This has all the earmarks of an XY question so far.  Ask is insulation is OK when the materials, geometry, purpose of system is undefined nor any meaningful Engineering Specs.  It could be interesting and greatly improved.  until then -1

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I'm well aware there is a difference between propylene glycol and ethylene glycol. Just as there is a difference between ethanol and methanol, in humans. However, that does not make it a "natural flavor." That assignment was made with the explicit purpose of hiding the fact that propylene glycol is being added to products such as apple juice from the public. Just as it is legal to have only ONE out of TEN apples be "fresh crop" while NINE other apples are really from cold storage and may be as old as 2 yrs. You can buy a box of fresh crop apples and see only 1:10.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 All completely legal in the US. The determination of the safety of propylene glycol for human consumption is at least "not yet well determined." I spent hours pouring over the specific liver pathways (and there is not just one, by the way) for propylene glycol. (The first step is ketalization.) In any case, I don't consider it an ***honest*** tactic and I know ***exactly*** why it was included under that heading in food product contents listings. (The record is very clear about it.) It's purpose was to hide it. Plain and simple.

Comment: I don’t understand it but it may act to reduce oxidation or bacterial growth by forming into tartaric acid

Comment: Wiki says “ very low toxicity”

Comment: I have tested Nynas Transformer oil which can vary from 16kV/mm to 75kV/mm depending on level of contamination levels from moisture, silicate dust and other natural airborne particles in a transformer factory. Generally it must pass 25kV/mm from supplier sample tests after 5 minutes of zapping contaminants and a few ramps of tests ignored.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I know what Wiki says. I also know what I read in NCBI research papers on the liver and its pathways. It turns out, for example, that propylene glycol causes grand-mal seizures in my daughter. (Tested, and verified. It's due to the metabolites that result.) Point is, it is safe for some. Not safe for others. And I have to tell you that a grand mal seizure has resulted in broken arms, 3rd degree burns, and many broken teeth in my daughter. (Not that they were caused by specific consumption, in these cases, of propylene glycol. Only that they could have been.)

Comment: that's dreadful @jonk. The Dr's  told me not to change  my gabapentin intake too rapidly otherwise it may cause a seizure unrelated to the neuropathy nerve pain it was supposed to subdue

Answer (score 2):

The relative permeability \$\mu_r\$ of transformer oil will be 1.0 so the oil will not affect the inductance. Your tub, if made of conductive material, will affect the inductance.

The relative permittivity \$\epsilon_r\$ is probably in the 2.0-2.5 range so it will add capacitance. It also will have a non-zero dissipation factor, which increases with temperature.

[Here](https://ergonnsa.com/files/naphthenic/hyvolt-ii.pdf) is a typical datasheet for a modern PCB-free transformer oil with references to the ASTM standards that are relevant (eg. ASTM D3487). If you look for other oils that meet the standards you'll find a number of suppliers.

[image]

If you are in Europe you'll be looking at a different set of similar standards most likely.

Moisture needs to be kept out- it will decrease the dielectric strength, for one thing.

You can buy this at distributors in 5 or 55 U.S. gallon quantities. It's not particularly expensive.